# Tkinter: Calling an app function from another module

Tags: python, tkinter, dynamic, module, widget

I've created a little dummy project to exemplify what my objective is:

The app consists of two widgets, a Button and a Text area. When button is pressed, calls another module. The called module then calls back to the mainframe and accesses the "insert text" function, acting like a log of the code running in the called module.
Below is a simple example of what im trying to achieve.

The structure of the project is:

- main.py
- another (folder)

  - module.py

main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
#from tkmacosx import Button ignore if not in MacOS

from another import module

class Example():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.main_frame = Frame(root)
        self.main_frame.pack()
        self.text = Text(self.main_frame)
        self.text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.button = Button(self.main_frame,
            height = 25,
            width = 150,
            command = self.call_another_module)
        self.button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.new_text_line("Start.")

    def call_another_module(self):
        self.new_text_line("button press!\n")
        module.Generic_class()

    def new_text_line(self, message):
        self.text.insert(INSERT, message + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Example")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

module.py

```
import tkinter as tk

#Shenanigans to import main
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir)

import main


class Generic_class():
    #code of something
    #call new_text_line function 
    main.Example().new_text_line("Hurray!")
    #continue code
```

***I am aware that calling the main module as displayed in the example above is incorrect since I'm calling the app instance again.***

Would greatly appreciate feedback on this particular issue and other approaches to this problem.

Comment: There will be circular import issue.  Better to move the class `Example` to a new module.  Also better refactor your code because `Example` class refers `Generic_class` and vice versa.

Comment: I didn't consider a circular import, thank you for the advice. The main focus of this issue is to access new_text_line() from outside the main file, if of course is doable in Tkinter.

Comment: you should send it as argument `Generic_class(self.text)` and not create `main.Example()` because it creates new instance of `Example()` which doesn't have text from original instance of `Example()`. BTW: see other widgets - they take `root` or other widget as first argument to have access to parent. The same do in `Generic_class()` - get parent as first argument to have acccess to original Example()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See other widgets - all of them get other widget as first argument and it is its parent.

The same do in your class - get parent widget as first argment

```
class GenericClass(): # PEP8: `UpperCaseNames` for classes

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.new_text_line("Hurray!")
```

And then you can create it

```
module.GenericClass(self)
```

and it will have access to all functions/variables in `Example`

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, my issue was in fact accessing the app properties after running the mainloop(). Going to try on my actual project, cheers!